# Get back free space lost with resize2fs

Tags: filesystems, partition

I resized an EXT4 partition with `resize2fs`, but it was after the action completed that I found out it only shrinked the filesystem, not the partition. How can I grow the filesystem to be the size of the partition again? (My question isn't about shrinking the partition,  I did that with GParted. My question is about how to grow the filesystem back to the size of the now smaller partition.) GParted says I have 11.56 gigabytes used (the size of all my files added together is 4.4 gigs), while `df` says 4.4 gigs.
Output of `df -h`:
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use%
/dev/sda4       443G  4.4G  439G   1%`
Output of `fsck /dev/sda`:
`Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda4   975955968 1918963711 943007744 449.7G Linux filesystem`

Comment: What size is your partition if it's not around 443GB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default action of `resize2fs` is to grow the filesystem to occupy the whole partition, so you just need to run `resize2fs /dev/sda4`.

Indeed, this is what I think most people do to shrink a filesystem:

1. shrink the FS to some size that lies between the minimum size (defined by the volume of files already in the filesystem) and the desired size
2. resize the partition to the desired size
3. resize the FS to fit the partition

Maybe nowadays partitioning tools check the size of the FS so that it doesn't get truncated when shrinking the partition too much, but it's not something one wants to check too often!